# Using Parallel Stream block all other threads

Tags: java

I have a small program that starts 4 threads, each of thread count even number to 20.
I am doing a sleep on one of the thread execution only but seems all other threads are blocked waiting the blocked thread to resume.

Why enable the parallelism stream processing is causing such behaviour?

```
  public class Program {

        static int first;

        public static void main(String[] a) throws InterruptedException {
            new Program().runTasks();
        }

        private void runTasks() throws InterruptedException {
            int value = 20;
            ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            executorService.execute(() -> numberOfEvens(value));
            first++;
            executorService.execute(() -> numberOfEvens(value));
            executorService.execute(() -> numberOfEvens(value));
            executorService.execute(() -> numberOfEvens(value));

            executorService.shutdown();
        }

        private void numberOfEvens(int val) {

            System.out.println(IntStream.range(1, val).parallel().filter(this::isEven).count());
        }

        private void delay(int d) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(d);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                // Do Nothing
            }
        }

        private boolean isEven(int n) {
            if (first == 1)
                delay(1000);
            return n % 2 == 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is assuming the `static` remains available to the thread after start.

The `first` variable may have a value of zero **when you create the first lambda** but it will have value `1` soon after and almost certainly by the time the first call to `delay` occurrs.

This achieves what you want - it prints *Delaying* 20 times as expected:

```
public static class Program {

    public static void main(String[] a) throws InterruptedException {
        new Program().runTasks();
    }

    private void runTasks() throws InterruptedException {
        int value = 20;
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        executorService.execute(() -> numberOfEvens(value, true));
        executorService.execute(() -> numberOfEvens(value, false));
        executorService.execute(() -> numberOfEvens(value, false));
        executorService.execute(() -> numberOfEvens(value, false));
        executorService.execute(() -> numberOfEvens(value, false));
        executorService.execute(() -> numberOfEvens(value, false));
        executorService.execute(() -> numberOfEvens(value, false));
        executorService.execute(() -> numberOfEvens(value, false));
        executorService.execute(() -> numberOfEvens(value, false));
        executorService.execute(() -> numberOfEvens(value, false));
        executorService.execute(() -> numberOfEvens(value, false));
        executorService.execute(() -> numberOfEvens(value, false));
        executorService.execute(() -> numberOfEvens(value, false));

        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    private void numberOfEvens(int val, boolean first) {

        System.out.println(IntStream.range(1, val).parallel().filter(n -> isEven(n, first)).count());
    }

    private void delay(int d) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Delaying");
            Thread.sleep(d);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // Do Nothing
        }
    }

    private boolean isEven(int n, boolean first) {
        if (first) {
            delay(1000);
        }
        return n % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You never initialize ***first*** so it starts as 0, from sun doc:

> It's not always necessary to assign a value when a field is declared.
>   Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a
>   reasonable default by the compiler. Generally speaking, this default
>   will be **zero** or null, depending on the data type. Relying on such
>   default values, however, is generally considered bad programming
>   style.

So when you are doing `first++` it's value is **1** and so all the other threads sleeps. 
Initializing first to 1 should solve the problem, like this:

```
static int first = 1;
```

### Default Values

[image]